# Find index of a list where that list is part of a larger list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have various complex lists such as

```
lista = [3,4,[5,[1,2],0]
listb = [[3,4],0,[1,5],2]
```

I need to find the position of the items in the top list. My output would be item, index for the first list:

```
0 3
1 2
2 2
3 0
4 1
5 2
```

So 5,1,2 are in position 3.

In the other list:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 0
4 0
5 2
```

The number of sublists can vary and each sublist can have sublists.

In order to simplify, I have searched for any list with a "," and flatted that into 1 sublist.

I could have a list of individual elements and lists but I could not get the indexes.  I also tried converting the individual elements into a single item list and appending it but I still cannot get the index of the sublist.

Comment: please post your code and tryings

Comment: Fix your `lista`, it's missing a closing bracket somewhere which makes your desired output ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that flattens a given list by iterating through the list items and recursively flattens an item if it is a list. Use the `enumerate` function to generate list indices and output them as the second item of a tuple:

```
def flatten(l):
    return [(n, i) for i, v in enumerate(l) for n, _ in (flatten(v) if isinstance(v, list) else ((v, 0),))]
```

so that given:

```
lista=[3,4,[5,[1,2]],0]
listb=[[3,4],0,[1,5],2]
```

the following:

```
print(flatten(lista))
print(flatten(listb))
```

will output:

```
[(3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (0, 3)]
[(3, 0), (4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (5, 2), (2, 3)]
```

or if you prefer the output to be sorted by the item values:

```
print(sorted(flatten(lista)))
print(sorted(flatten(listb)))
```

will output:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 2)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

```
def find_index(val, lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if val == x:
            return i
        elif type(x) is list:  # or type(x) not in {float, int}
            try:
                find_index(val, x)
                # matched without error
                return i
            except ValueError:
                # not in list
                pass
    # not found
    raise ValueError('{} is not in the list'.format(val))
```

This uses the `enumerate` function to get items and their indexes from the list. Then it tests each item directly against the required value if possible. If the item is a list, it checks that recursively instead.

Test:

```
lst = [[3, 4], 0, [1, [5]], 2]
for x in range(6):
    print x, find_index(x, lst)

# 0 1
# 1 2
# 2 3
# 3 0
# 4 0
# 5 2
```

If you want to be able to work with any type of iterable (not just `list`s), you could try this more general code, but it's harder to follow:

```
def find_index(val, values):
    try:
        # Search list of items
        for i, x in enumerate(values):
            try:
                find_index(val, x)  # any error?
                return i            # succeeded
            except ValueError:
                pass
    except TypeError:
        # not a list, just an item
        if values == val:
            return 0                # found
    # not found
    raise ValueError('{} is not in the list'.format(val))
```